# How can I separate AsyncTask from Activity?

Tags: android

I would like to use ClassAsyncTask to a separate class, Im trying to but not having a success. I need a clear Information on How to do this one or an Idea How can I do it. Thanks in Advance.

```
public class XMLParser extends Activity {

    String targetURL = "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml";
    TextView name[], website[], category[];
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* layout to display the view */
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(1);

        /* Set the ContentView to layout for display */
        this.setContentView(linearLayout);

        ClassAsyncTask asyncTask = new GBAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.execute(targetURL);

    }

    //
    public class ClassAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

                /* Handling XML */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                /* Send URL to parse XML Tags */
                URL sourceUrl = new URL(targetURL);

                /* Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        /* Return-value from doInBackground */
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            /* Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
            SiteList sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

            /* Assign TextView array length by arrayList size */
            name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
            website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
            category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

            int h = sitesList.getName().size();
            /* Set the result text in TextView and add it to layout */
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                name[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                name[i].setText("Name = " + sitesList.getName().get(i));
                website[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                website[i]
                        .setText("Website = " + sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
                category[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                category[i].setText("Website Category = "
                        + sitesList.getCategory().get(i));
                linearLayout.addView(name[i]);
                linearLayout.addView(website[i]);
                linearLayout.addView(category[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should leave AsyncTask as a nested class, having it separate is not a good idea.

Comment: I had wondered the same thing a while ago, but came to the conclusion it's not a good idea to do it. Sure it's more reusable and it's better design-wise. But if you'd want your assync task to work properly, you'd have to keep references to your activities in some kind of controller, so you can access it from within the async task

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comments. But the Idea is to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `ClassAsyncTask` from another class by using `XMLParser.ClassAsyncTask`.

If you want to make the subclass independent of the parent class (to broaden its usage), you should make sure to remove any reference to class variables of the parent class. In your case this is `targetURL`.
You could do this by creating a class constructor that stores the target URL.

Comment: ok I created a constructor for the targetURL. The only error or having red lines is in my onPostExecute... the getApplicationContext(), how can I solve this one. thanks

Comment: Ok, then you have to pass the `Context ctx` as well in the constructor. You can then use it for `getApplicationContext()`, like `ctx.getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate it and hand over the current context and an interface implementation for the callback method in the constructor, e.g.:

```
public class JSONLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> callback;
    private Context context;
    ..

    public JSONLoader(Context context, AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> cb) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = cb;
    }

    ..
    // callback method implemented by calling activity:
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // call callback method
        callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    }
}
```

The task is started from an activity this way (note that it doesn't need to extend `FragmentActivity`. It can extend `Activity` or any of its subclasses as well):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ..
        JSONLoader jsonLoader = new JSONLoader(this, this);
        jsonLoader.execute(getString(R.string.datasource_url_list));
    }

    // from AsyncTaskCompleteListener interface
    public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
        // your callback method implementation
    }
    ..
}
```

And this is the interface that can be used by your activities to define different callback methods:

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener<T> {
    public void onTaskComplete(T result);

}
```

Comment: w8. w8. w8. I cant understand it. Can you make it to my code? I'm just a beginner.

Comment: It is not that difficult: MainActivity = XMLParser, JSONLoader = ClassAsyncTask. If you want to have different callback methods you need the AsyncTaskCompleteListener as glue.

Comment: Matt Handy, Need your help in making this one work because I cant make it to work.

Comment: Please describe what errors you get. I would start separating the task in a new class - first without the interface.

Comment: Ok let's start from the beginning. I separate the ClassAsyncTask to it's own class - ClassAsyncTask.java, then the variables(name,website,category,targetURL) have red lines.

Comment: Fix your imports. Your inner class references variables from the outer class. Add a constructor where you hand over these variables to the new class.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. Let me work with this constructor., it's only the first step right?

Comment: How to pass the getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Pass it in the constructor, such like `public ClassAsyncTask(Context ctx ...)`

Comment: Sorry, but all those things are java basics. I posted a complete example with a constructor taking the context as parameter `public JSONLoader(Context context, AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> cb) {        this.context = context; this.callback = cb; }`

Comment: Yes, I see. Right now I am learning android programming as well and it is not that easy (even with some experience in java programming). Without that experience I would be frustrated as well ;-).